# How do I add data to an interface that is taken as an argument in Go?

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm just picking up go, so apologies if my terminology isn't precise. My end goal is to add the name of a cachebusted CSS file to the layout template of my Go application. The CSS file built on the fly when the application starts up so can't be hardcoded. In my template file I have this:

```
//More html here
<link href="{{.CSSFile}}" rel="stylesheet">
//more html here
```

I have a Render method on a View type like shown below. It takes `data interface{}` as an argument and then runs `ExecuteTemplate`. It is called by every controller in one way or another that sends the `data` argument and exposes information. I know how to add it as data from the controller that then calls the `Render` method, but I obviously don't want to add the CSS file in every single controller action, so it makes the most sense to add it in the Render function one time and have it added to the data that gets passed to `ExecuteTemplate`. My issue is how do I add this information to the data already being passed to `Render` and then pass that whole of information to `ExecuteTemplate`. What I have below works for the CSS file, but it obviously doesn't send along the `data` that was passed to the original `Render` argument.

```
type View struct {
    Template *template.Template
    Layout   string
}


func (v *View) Render(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}) error {
    d := Data{}
    d.AddCSSFile()
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    err := v.Template.ExecuteTemplate(w, v.Layout, d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "<h1>Something went wrong. Please contact us at support")
    }
    return nil
}

type Data struct {
    Alerts  []Alert
    Yield   interface{}
    CSSFile interface{}
}


func (d *Data) AddCSSFile() {
    ss, _ := filepath.Glob("./assets/site-*.css")
    fp := strings.Join(ss, "")
    _, d.CSSFile = filepath.Split(fp)
}
```

I've created a gist which, not entirely complete, is a little more fleshed out of what I'm trying to do: 
https://gist.github.com/codelitt/549a68149add0482c6dc2514a46aa580

Comment: Just stuff your `data` into your `d`. For that `type Data` needs a new field `Data interface{}` and then just do `d.Data = data`. Would be obvious if you didn't use `interface{}`.

Comment: @Volker Okay. Thank you. It seems to be working, but is breaking another part of my app which I have to investigate now. Think that puts me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you're asking but if what you want is to combine the `data interface{}` argument with the `d := Data{}` value inside `Render`, then you could do something like this...

```
// ...

func (v *View) Render(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}) error {
    p := Page{Data:data}
    p.AddCSSFile()
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    err := v.Template.ExecuteTemplate(w, v.Layout, p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "<h1>Something went wrong. Please contact us at support")
    }
    return nil
}

type Page struct {
    Alerts  []Alert
    Yield   interface{}
    CSSFile interface{}
    Data interface{}
}
func (p *Page) AddCSSFile() {
     // ...
}
```

**Edit:** Or you could also just initialize an anonymous struct value and pass it to `ExecuteTemplate` without having to change you existing `Data` type.

```
// ...

err := v.Template.ExecuteTemplate(w, v.Layout, struct{
    Data
    Args interface{}
}{Data:d, Args:data})

// ...
```

**Edit2:** So if I understand your comment correctly the `data interface{}` argument passed to the `Render` method could in some or all instances be or contain a value of a type that matches one of the `Data` fields' types, in which case you would like to set that value to that field so as to pass it together to the `ExecuteTemplate` method. At least one solution to that, as you've already found out, is to use type assertion. Below is a slightly modified version of your example from the comment in the context of your original example from the question.

```
func (v *View) Render(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}) error {
    d := Data{}
    d.AddCSSFile()
    if alerts, ok := data.([]Alert); ok {
        d.Alerts = alerts
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    err := v.Template.ExecuteTemplate(w, v.Layout, d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "<h1>Something went wrong. Please contact us at support")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm taking a look now. Both answers and another persons comments start breaking other things while they fix the initial issue so I'm digging deeper and will report back for what worked. I'm leaning towards your first answer (similar to the other commenter's answer as well)

Comment: @mkovpriva your answer got me most of the way there - if you would like to amend it I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

I didn't need to add an interface called `Data` to my `Data struct`. I just needed to know how to add data to a struct and do type assertions on an interface type.

I ended up with something basically like what you have in the first answer but without changing the Data struct. Just doing something like this worked:

`d := Data{Alerts: data.(Data).Alerts, Yield: data}`

Comment: thanks. I marked as correct and I'm going to alter my setup a bit to make it more forgiving as you've shown with the if statements. Sorry if things were unclear.

Comment: @codelitt no worries, framing a question in such a way as to solicit the answer you're looking for is not always easy, at least I know it's not easy for me ;). And in the end your's wasn't bad, so just keep on keeping on.